On firing a React Change Event, URL displays the previous event
I'm relatively new to React, and I'm solving a sample problem.
I am supposed to sort the data by Name or by order, on event change or on click.
Here is the component code;
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const DisplayShops = () => {
  const [shopList, setShopList] = useState([]);
  const [tenant , setTenant] = useState('');
  const [leaseOrder, setLeaseOrder] = useState('');
  /* On mounting the component, shop list should be fetched from the backend using GET API "http://localhost:8000/property" */

  const fetchData = async (req,res) => {
    let r = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/property");
    setShopList(r.data.shops);
  }
  useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, []);

  const fetchWithFilter = async (e) => {
    /* Code goes here to filter the data by sending the query param with the API Request "http://localhost:8000/property" */
    /* query params:
        leaseAmount -(values: "" , "asc" or  "desc")
        tenantName  -(values: "" or any string) */
        const {name,value} = e.target;
    if(name === 'searchByOrder') {
      setLeaseOrder(value)
    }
    if(name === 'searchByTenant') {
      setTenant(String(value))
    }
    let url = `http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=${leaseOrder}&tenantName=${tenant}`;
    let r = await axios.get(url);
    setShopList(r.data.shops);
    console.log(url)
  };

  return (
    <div className="displayShop">
      <h3>Shop Details</h3>
      <table className="shop-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Shop Details</th>
            <th>
              Lease <br />
              Amount
              <button data-testid="ascending" name='searchByOrder' value='asc' onClick={fetchWithFilter}>↑</button>
              {/*On ↑ click , call the function fetchWithFilter to fetch data in ascending order of leaseAmount*/}
              <button data-testid="descending" name='searchByOrder' value='desc' onClick={fetchWithFilter}>↓</button>
              {/*On ↓ click , call the function fetchWithFilter to fetch data in descending order of leaseAmount*/}
            </th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>
              Tenant name
              <form data-testid="searchForm">
                {/*On form submit , call the function fetchWithFilter to filter data that matches the given tenant name */}
                <input type="search" placeholder="Filter by name" data-testid="searchName" name='searchByTenant' value={tenant} onChange={fetchWithFilter}/>
              </form>
            </th>
            <th>Tenant Mobile</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>End date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {shopList && <tbody>
          {/* Display each shop details in individual table rows. Follow the template below */}

          {/*Template for rows*/}
          {shopList && shopList.map((s) =>
          <tr data-testid="shop-row" key={s._id}>
            <td>{`Shop: ${s.shopNo}`}, {`Floor: ${s.floorNo}`}</td>
            <td>{`${s.leaseAmount}`}</td>
            <td>{s.occupied ? 'Occupied' : 'Unoccupied'}</td>
            <td>{s.tenantName}</td>
            <td>{s.tenantMobile}</td>
            <td>{s.leaseStartDate}</td>
            <td>{s.leaseEndDate}</td>
          </tr>)}
          {/*End of template*/}
        </tbody>}
        {/*Display this tfoot only if no records are displayed as result of filter*/}
        {!shopList && <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="7">No record found</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DisplayShops;

My issue is that, when I handle a click or change event, the previous URL is being executed.
For instance, if I click on the ↑ icon, after the component first fetches data, then the fetchWithFilter funcion sends the get request with the link;
http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=&tenantName=

But it was supposed to send leaseAmount=asc and not empty parameter.
And when I click again,
http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=asc&tenantName=

This is executed.
Now when I click on ↓(desc button),
http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=asc&tenantName=

When I click desc again;
http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=desc&tenantName=

Now I get what I want. But this should not be the case.
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and would really appreciate if somebody takes a look at this. Thanks in advance!
EDIT:
The problem is with the function fetchWithFilter.
The issue is that the values updated using setTenant() and setLeaseOrder() are available in the next re-render, as commented by @Soman.
I tried doing the following;
const fetchWithFilter = async (e) => {
    /* Code goes here to filter the data by sending the query param with the API Request "http://localhost:8000/property" */
    /* query params:
        leaseAmount -(values: "" , "asc" or  "desc")
        tenantName  -(values: "" or any string) */
        const {name,value} = e.target;
        let lo=''
        let te=''
    if(name === 'searchByOrder') {
      // setLeaseOrder(value)
      lo=value;
    }
    else if(name === 'searchByTenant') {
      // setTenant(String(value))
      setTenant(value)
      te = tenant
    }
    let url = `http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=${lo}&tenantName=${te}`;
    let r = await axios.get(url);
    setShopList(r.data.shops);
    console.log(url)
  };

I created 2 variables, lo and te, where I store 'asc' or 'desc' in lo. But I have to updated tenant, as I have given value={tenant} in the input search box.
It works fine for asc or desc, that is with respect to leaseOrder. But the issue persists for tenant.
EDIT2: Thanks to @ChukwujiobiCanon, I'm able to get the changed value in the same render, which I feel is much more progress than before. But now I'm unable to combine multiple parameters.
EDIT3: The question which a mod has marked as similar, hasn't resolved my problem. The answer in the marked question hasn't even been approved by the questioner, so I'm not sure if it is true.
FINAL EDIT:
I finally found the answer to my question. I have used useEffect(), modified the fetchData function, to be called everytime there's a change in

tenant
ListOrder (renamed it to ListAmount)

components.
Here is the changed code.
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let url =
        tenant === "" && leaseAmount === ""
          ? `http://localhost:8000/property`
          : `http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=${leaseAmount}&tenantName=${tenant}`;
      let r = await axios.get(url);
      console.log(url);
      setShopList(r.data.shops);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [tenant, leaseAmount]);

  const fetchWithFilter = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { name, value } = e.target;

    if (name === "searchByTenant") {
      setTenant(value);
    }
    if (name === "searchByOrder") {
      setLeaseAmount(value);
    }
  };

Thanks for helping me out guys!

Use a data-loading hook such as swr to make your life easier.

Perform the needed action before performing synchronization with the GUI.

@ChukwujiobiCanon, I'm not sure what to do. Could you please give me a sample code, so I can work on this?

Alright I’ll write up an answer.

The best approach is to perform action before you perform synchronization with the GUI:
const fetchWithFilter = async (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;

    let url = new URL("property", "http://localhost:8000");

    if(name === 'searchByOrder') {
      url.search = new URLSearchParams({leaseAmount: value});
      setLeaseOrder(value);
    }

    if(name === 'searchByTenant') {
      url.search = new URLSearchParams({tenantName: value});
      setTenant(value);
    }

    let r = await axios.get(url.href);
    setShopList(r.data.shops);
};
React batches ”state-GUI” synchronization so it is not a good idea to wait for this to occur before you use the updated state to run other logic.[1]

[1] Wait for state update only if you really have to.

Hi, thank you so much for your answer. It's now capturing data in the same render. But I'm unable to add multiple parameters to the URL, for some reason. I literally copied and pasted your code after writing my own, and the issue persists. Please help, thanks again!

To add more parameters, pass these to the object used to construct URLSearchParams. Add them as key: value pairs.

I will have to add only one value pair each time, which gets overwritten as soon as the fetchWithFilter function is called again. To resolve this, I have saved each of the updated values every call to 2 global scoped variables, and used url object as mentioned by you. Now the issue again comes up.

What exactly are you trying to do? It seems ”add multiple parameters” doesn’t mean exactly what you say here from how you are trying to do it. What values are you trying to add as multiple parameters here?

React will batch "setLeaseOrder", "setTenant" calls that occur within the same event handler or lifecycle method and does a single re-render.
Once the setLeaseOrder and setTenant is executed, the value in leaseOrder and tenant variable are available in next re-render.
Since you are storing value in lease order and tenant, you could just use this variable in URL instead of value from useState.
let url = `http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=${value}&tenantName=${String(value)}`;


Hi! Thanks for the reply. I understood now the part where you mentioned about the values being in the next re-render. But directly using the 'value' isn't an option for me as I use iit to grab value of both leaseOrder and tenant.

let url = `http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=${leaseOrder}&tenantName=${tenant}`;

You need to create two different url for each cases you want.
if(leastOrder){let url = http://localhost:8000/property? + leaseAmount=${leaseOrder}

else if(tenent) {let url = http://localhost:8000/property? + tenantName=${tenant}}

else if (leastOrder && tenent) {let url = `http://localhost:8000/property?leaseAmount=${leaseOrder}&tenantName=${tenant}`}


Hi, thanks for the reply. This is not my primary issue, as I'm okay with leaseAmount and tenant being black, when passed to the url. Still, I gave it a try and it is unable to capture the tenant value to the url.

please give a working example link of your project in stackblitz or codesandbox.
